# NPV and IRR in Spotfire 7.6

Tags: spotfire

I'm aware that `NPV` and `IRR` are possible in `Spotfire 7.7` using `TERR Agg` functions.

I have a data file with cash-flows and associated dates. I need to be able to select sub-sets of that data set and calculate a live `NPV` / `IRR` result.

Does anyone have a work-around to do this in 7.6?

Answer (score 0):

We have time series data with cashflow as well.  I calculate a new column that discounts every value and then sums and aggregates those as needed for the NPV calculation.

Simple calc column :

```
[Cashflow ($M)] / (1.1 ^ (Year([Date]) - 2018))
```

We discount at a 10% rate. 
My understanding is that you need to use TERR for IRR. A good post on it is here:

https://community.tibco.com/questions/i-am-new-spotfire-and-am-trying-setup-dynamic-irr-calculation-given-cashflows-i-want-be